# Copy and paste things into the next empty cell in column

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to figure this out for ages. I've found an answer on StackOverflow but I get object error when trying to use it. I want to copy a set of data from a sheet based on a condition and then paste it in the next empty cell in a column on another sheet. This is my code:

```
Public list As Worksheet
Public bsawt As Worksheet

Sub Check2()
Set bsawt = Sheets("BSAW_TABLE")
Set list = Sheets("LIST")

lastrow = list.Cells(Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
For x = 13 To lastrow

If list.Range("K" & x).Value = "BSAW" Then list.Range("L" & x).Copy Destination:=bsawt.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: *but I get object error when trying to use it* Which line?

Comment: the copy-paste line: If list.Range("K" & x).Value = "BSAW" Then list.Range("L" & x).Copy Destination:=bsawt.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: If you've got nothing in column A you will go the last row and then attempt to go one row further down. Try instead `bsawt.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).Offset(1, 0)`.

Comment: Or something only in A1.

Comment: There is a header in A1, I'll try your version.

Comment: Yep it worked wonders, can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as resolved?

Comment: To explain what went wrong here: `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` does exactly the same as manually select A1 end then press Ctrl+ArrowDown. If there is no data in the sheet (or only a header) this will select the very last row in the sheet. `Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup)` is the opposite: Select the very last cell in the column and press Ctrl+ArrowUp and this selects the last used cell in that column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have nothing in column A, or an entry in A1 only, then copying to this destination

```
Destination:=bsawt.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

is equivalent to going to the last cell in column A in the worksheet and then attempting to go down one further row, which is clearly an impossibility. See also @PEH's comment.

Instead, work up from the bottom.

```
Destination:=bsawt.Range("A" & rows.count).End(xlup).Offset(1, 0)
```